# Problemas com comando import e from/import

Tags: python, pycharm, import

Estou com um problema no meu programa.
Quando eu digito "from math import sqrt (ou qualquer outra coisa", a biblioteca math não é reconhecida pelo pycharm.
Segue o código:

```
from math import sqrt
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
r = math.sqrt(n)
print('A raiz de {} é {}'.format(n, math.ceil(r)))
```

Talvez seja um problema bem simples. Porém ainda não consegui resolve-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está importando o módulo `math`, mas apenas a função `sqrt` diretamente.

Para resolver isso você só precisa mudar a linha `import` disto:

```
from math import sqrt
```

Para isto:

```
import math
```

Agora, se você quiser usar as funções sem precisar sempre adicionar o prefixo `math.`, você pode importar as funções `sqrt` e `ceil` desta forma:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
```

E nas linhas correspondentes, você chamaria as funções desta forma:

```
r = sqrt(n)
print('A raiz de {} é {}'.format(n, ceil(r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, bem vindo(a) ao site!

No seu código, você não importou a biblioteca math inteira, somente o math.sqrt().
Logo, o math.ceil() não estará disponível.
Para resolver:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
```

ou

```
import math
```

A primeira opção é melhor por pesar menos o programa. A segunda importa coisa que você não vai usar.

Abraço!